# How does one get around a destroyed Cyberdisc in XCOM: Enemy Unknown?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I just destroyed a Cyberdisk in the "Gangplank" mission, and the corpse has completely blocked the way forward. Is there something I can do to get past it, or do I have to find some way around?

Comment: Is the wreck on fire? Fire blocks movement, but it'll go out in a few turns. If not, you can just go around it; the only chokepoint on that map that you absolutely have to go through is the front door, right at the start. After that, there are always at least two paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Corpses should not block the way forward. If a corpse is preventing you from moving forwards, it is likely bugged, and your best bet is to load from an older save or restart the mission.

If you're playing Ironman mode, you may be entirely out of luck, sadly.

Comment: Ha! Saved and reloaded and now it'll let me pass. Ok, game bug. I'm not going insane!

Answer (score 4):

As Raven Dreamer has said, corpses and wrecks should not themselves block movement. However, when Cyberdiscs explode they tend to start fires, and soldiers cannot move through fire (unless wearing Titan armour).

In Gangplank, there is usually a Cyberdisc close to one of the entrances into the penultimate room - a large open area with two power conduits. I too have destroyed this in the doorway and blocked my own way! If this is where you are, you have two options:

1. Wait a few turns - the fire will go out.
2. Go around: There are two "ground level" entrances to that room, and you can also walk on the galleries to either side and drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Blow a hole in the wall, walk through said hole, kill everything inside. Done.

Comment: Is there any particular trick to blowing a hole in the wall?  Good aim?  or is it just that straightforward?

Comment: You might not be able to - unfortunately, you can't deliberately shoot at walls, so if you're out of free-aim weapons (launcher/grenades), you're out of luck.